# how to loop this array to get each keys and its values

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$email_recipient = array(

    "All user accounts"=> 1,
    "Not enrolled users" => 2,
    "All enrolled users" =>3,
    "Users in progress" =>4,
    "Completed users"=>5,
    "Completed and passed"=>6,
    "Completed and failed" => 7,
    "Not enrolled + in progress" => 8
);

$notification_type = array(
    "Scheduled Message" => array(1 => $email_recipient),
    "Countdown Reminder" => array(2 => array("Not enrolled users" => $email_recipient["Not enrolled users"]),array("Users in progress" => $email_recipient["Users in progress"]),array("Not enrolled + in progress" => $email_recipient["Not enrolled + in progress"])),
    "New Joiner Alert" => array(3 => array("All new joiners" => 9)),
);
```

how can i get values of Scheduled Message as 1 , Countdown Reminder as 2 ,New Joiner Alert as 3

Comment: `foreach($notification_type as $key => $value)` will achieve this unless i'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: here $value return array

Comment: Which can then be looped through to get all the values in the first element of `$notification_type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think StackOverflow is a place where people find solutions for you. Post a try, give an hypothesis on how you could solve this. And the communityt can help you. Posting the question waiting for the answer is not the right way to stay here.

Anyway, you can get the value (if i understand you question):

```php
$new_array = [];
foreach ($notification_type as $key => $value) {
    $new_array[$key] = array_keys($value)[0];
}
```

Now your array `$new_array` has 3 items:

```
$new_array = [
    "Scheduled Message" => 1,
    "Countdown Reminder" => 2,
    "New Joiner Alert" = 3
];
```

Comment: While correct, the first part is redundant for the answer.

Comment: @Marco Ghinassi

Comment: @Marco Ghinassi   - how to populate the second dropdown using the selected value in first dropdown? here first dropdown  values are $new_array , and I want to populate its subarray values in second dropdown on its change

Comment: I think about a couple of solutions.
you can add a recursive action into the foreach in order to  create se subarray, and naming the subarray with the key of parent array (pay attention to camelize the varname)

example:
$new_array["countdown Reminder"] =2

choose it so subarray will be
${str_replace(" ", "", array_key($new_array["countdown Reminder"]))}
that is $countdownReminder